# How to store session data into database in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

In this case I have 2 tables in database "users" and "posts".
First table extends basic user data (id, firstname, lastname, username, mail, passwords etc...) Second one is about posts (id, title, text, author etc...)

So when user  gonna create a post, he need to fill title field and text field, author field should be filled with username pulled directly from session and stored it to db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this but what I suggest - do not store any user data in the session. When the user first logs in - create a "token" which is a long random string with maybe a datetime at the end of it for reference. Update the users table with the token, and save the token to the session.

When the user goes to another page - you grab the token from the session - and use that to return the user record from the database. You then have all the user details for whatever you need. This will get you out of the habit of storing any user, etc details in the session. This is much better for security and it makes your system easier to deal with long term. Otherwise you are in the position of having to update the user database table AND the session anytime the user makes any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your better and probably safter option here is to store your SESSION data in the database itself.

Have a look at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html. You will need to create a table in your DB called ci_sessions (or it is renameable in the config file) and then you could if you so needed pull the user name from the session.

Sessions stored on disk are fine (AFAIK) if its a dedicated box etc and you are in complete control of the code. Its when you are on a shared box they can't be relied upon.

Comment: With all respect that last part is not true at all. Disk based sessions work fine on shared hosting. The only 'catch' is you need to assign the folder to hold the session files in application/config.php and that folder should be above the public root html folder with correct permissions. So that part can be confusing for new people. Otherwise if you have a specific use case where file based sessions on shared hosting are unreliable i would be very interested to hear what it is.

Comment: I take your point. Obviously if a server wasn't setup well there is a risk that those session files might be readable - permissions, containment etc. A quick google found http://eddmann.com/posts/securing-sessions-in-php/ reflecting this point in his section titled 'Session Content Encryption'.

Answer (score 0):

When you login, create an array of things that will go into the cookie and session DB; An example

```
if (password_verify($pass1, $stored))
    {
      $data = array(
        'name'         => $row->name,
        'is_logged_in' => TRUE
      );
      $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

The name is part of the db record for the user. But is not part of the login. When you search for the user to log them in, name is one of the things you include in the query

Then, in your form input, simply set_value = $this->session->userdata('name')